# PHP - Access relationship to avoid nested foreach

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring

I have a web application where my users can:

1. Upload text documents
2. Send emails into my application.

Now both `Document` and `Email` will contain some kind of **text**. My users can then parse this text, based on a set of custom parsing rules that they will be able to apply to the text.

Now all documents and emails will ultimately belong to what I call a `Stream`. Consider these relationships:

`Stream.php`

```
// A stream can have many documents
public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Document::class);
}
//A stream can have many e-mails
public function emails()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Email::class);
}

//A stream can have many fields
public function fields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Field::class);
}

//A stream can have many field rules.
public function fieldrules()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(FieldRule::class, Field::class);
}
```

I have furthermore declared the inverse relationships for `Document.php` and `Email.php` - that both these to `belongsTo` a `Stream`.

Now I have below, where I need to access the field rules for a specific stream. For that, I use below:

```
    $stream = $document->stream()->first();
    $fields = $stream->fields()->with('rules')->get();

    foreach ($fields as $field) {

        foreach ($field->rules as $rule) {

           //Rule method.
           $rule->method;

       }
    }
```

As you can see, I have to create nested foreach loops, in order to get down to `$field->rules`.

If I `dd($fields)` I see that it contains the relation, like:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
   "rules" => Collection {#536 ▼
       #items: array:2 [▼
          0 => FieldRule {#554 ▶}
          1 => FieldRule {#552 ▶}
       ]
   }
]
```

But I cannot access it directly like:

```
foreach ($fields->rules as $rule){}
```

If I try, it gives me this error:

```
Property [rules] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Comment: did you mean `foreach ($field->rules` instead of `foreach ($fields->rules` (plural `$fields` is a collection, not a field)

Comment: And your `fieldrules` doesn't work for this? Wouldn't you be able to do `$rules = $stream->fieldrules`? Also, be careful when calling relationships with `()`; that's executing another DB call. I would think you could do `$fields = $document->stream->fields` depending on the Query to get `$document`.

Comment: @TimLewis How come `()` execute another query? What's the difference by doing: `$stream->fieldrules` and `$stream->fieldrules()`?

Comment: @TimLewis I just changed it to:
`$stream = $document->stream;` and then `$rules = $stream->fieldrules;` which seems to be working, and not requiring me to use a nested foreach loop. Thanks a lot, something was bugging me about my own code, and yours seems much more clean. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Sure thing. I'll add a blurb about using `()` and not using them too.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `()` executes another, fresh DB query. Plus you need to add a closure when using `()`.

For example, `$stream->fieldrules` should return a `Collection` (based on your relationship), but `$stream->fieldrules()` would return a `Builder` (the class behind DB queries), and when followed by `->get()` would return a `Collection` (the same thing as `$stream->fieldrules`, but with extra overhead)

Note that not using `()` will execute another query if the relationship is not eager loaded, so sometimes using `()` and not using `()` is the same thing. See the usage of `->with()` in the answer below.

To summarize, the code can be simplified using the following:

```
$document = Document::with([
  "stream", 
  "stream.fields", 
  "stream.fields.rules", 
  "stream.fieldrules"
])->first(); // or ->where("id", "=", $id)->first(), etc.
```

Note the usage of `->with()` to eager load the required relationships in a single query. `stream.fields` and `stream.fields.rules` might not required for this example, but I'm not sure of the logic under the hood for `hasManyThrough`

Then to alleviate the need for a nested `foreach()`, you can simply access the required relationships:

```
$rules = $document->stream->fieldrules;
```

You will still need to loop if you need to access a single field and it's rules, but since you've defined a `hasManyThrough` for a `stream`'s `fields` and `rules`, you can simply access that.